# Can a property of an object become other object's property, but still 'belongs to its owner'?

Tags: matlab, object, oop, properties

I don't know how to express 'property belongs to its owner' properly.

For example, I define classes 'student' and 'teacher'

```
classdef student < handle

    properties
        name
        homework
    end

    methods
         function obj = student(name)
            obj.name = name;
            obj.homework= struct;
            obj.homework.content='';
            obj.homework.mark=[];
         end
    end
end
```

```
classdef teacher < handle
    properties
        collection_homework
    end
end
```

```
A=student('A')
A.homework.content='A solution to a math problem'
B=teacher
```

My question is, according to my design intention, homework is a property of a student, or ‘A is the owner of his homework’. A 'sends' his homework to B, a teacher , so the homework becomes a property of B, but B is not 'the owner' of A's homework. What can teachers do is just to mark the homework and return the homework to students.

But when I try to "send A's homework to B", and B marks A's homework

```
B.collection_homework=A.homework % put A's homework into B's collection_homework
B.collection_homework.mark=100
```

I check A, but his homework still is all about content,  not mark

```
A.homework
ans = 
content: 'A solution to a math problem'
```

That means homework in B's collection_homework doesn't belong to A.

Unless I put 'the whole student' into teacher's collection_homework

```
B.collection_homework=A % put A into B's collection_homework
B.collection_homework.homework.mark=100
```

This time I can get B to mark A's homework. Check it

```
A.homework.marks
ans =
   100
```

But this is against with my design intention, because A seems to become B's subproperty. For example, B can change A's name by

```
B.collection_homework.name = 'C'
```

So what the code should be like to implement 'A send homework to B, and B mark it and send back to A'?

Comment: I think this is a problem of how OOP is taught. Forget about real-world relationships and real-world properties. Focus on what tasks you need to perform. For a “teacher” object to grade a “homework” object, the teacher doesn’t ever need to own or contain the “homework” object. Make a function `teacher.grade(student.homework)` or whatever. You probably don’t want the “student” object owning the “homework” object either. Maybe the “homework” object has a property “student” that identifies who wrote it.

Comment: And please, please, please don’t have “student” and “teacher” inherit from a common “person” class just because that is their relationship in real life. Unless there is functionality that they share, the “person” class is pointless and useless.

Comment: I know how to implement this. I can define 'homework' as another class, instead of a structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point is to define 'homework' as another class

```
classdef homework < handle
       
    properties
        content
        mark
    end
end
```

And change definition of 'student'

```
classdef student < handle & matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous

    properties
        name
        homework
    end

    methods
        function obj = student(name)
            obj.name = name;
            obj.homework = homework();
        end
    end
end
```

change definition of 'teacher'

```
classdef teacher < handle
    
    
    properties
        collection_homework
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = teacher()
            obj.collection_homework=homework.empty(0,1);
        end
    end
end
```

Now test it!

```
    A=student('A');
    A.homework.content='A solution to a math problem';
    B=teacher;
    B.collection_homework=A.homework;
    B.collection_homework.mark=85;
    
>>B.collection_homework
    
    ans = 
    
      homework - Properties:
    
        content: 'A solution to a math problem'
           mark: 85

>> A.homework

ans = 

  homework - Properties:

    content: 'A solution to a math problem'
       mark: 85
```

It seems that student and teacher have the same homework. Teacher grades it, and student recieve it.